# How to fetch users with the assignment_status='Open' OR assignment_status='Limited' with 'assignment_limited_threshold' value applied for them?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, postgresql-9.6

The application is  Loan Assignment System. I have list of users. Based on Skills and Assignment Status, I need to fetch eligible users list. There are three user related tables - **'user_info'**, **'user_skill'** & **'assignment_details'**. One loan related table which says to which user loan has been assigned i.e., **'loan_mapping'** table. To fetch eligible list, I have two main conditions.

1. The skill_id from the user_skill table should be 156.
2. The assignment_status for each user should be 'Open'  **OR** the assignment_status = 'Limited' along with 'assignment_limited_threshold' VALUE should be GREATER than **the total number of loans assigned to that user**.
   (In other words, total loans assignment count for each user shouldnot exceed this assignment_limited_threshold value)

user_id is the joining condition for user related tables.

The table definitions are mentioned below:

```
      CREATE TABLE public.user_info(
        user_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 
         nextval('lsa_user_info_user_id_seq'::regclass),
         email_id character varying(255),
       user_name character varying(255),
       lob_id  integer NOT NULL,
        status_id integer,
       CONSTRAINT user_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
      ) 
    WITH (
     OIDS=FALSE
    );
  ALTER TABLE public.lsa_user_info
    OWNER TO postgres;



    CREATE TABLE public.user_skill
       (
         user_id integer NOT NULL,
         skill_id integer NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT user_skill_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id, skill_id),
       CONSTRAINT fk_user_skill_skill_id FOREIGN KEY (skill_id)
       REFERENCES public.skill (skill_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
     CONSTRAINT fk_user_skill_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
   REFERENCES public.user_info (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION )
   WITH (
       OIDS=FALSE
    );
    ALTER TABLE public.user_skill
        OWNER TO postgres;



         CREATE TABLE public.assignment_details
         (
           user_id integer NOT NULL,
          role_id integer NOT NULL,
         lob_id  integer NOT NULL,
         assignment_status character varying,
         assignment_limited_threshold integer,
          CONSTRAINT lsa_assignment_details_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id, 
        role_id, lob_id  )
       )
     WITH (
        OIDS=FALSE
   );
         ALTER TABLE public.assignment_details
     OWNER TO postgres;



          CREATE TABLE public.loan_mapping 
          (
        loan_number           bigint NOT NULL,
         spoc_id               integer NOT NULL,

       loan_spoc_map_id      integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval 
        ('lsa_loan_spoc_mapping_loan_spoc_map_id_seq'::regclass),
          lob_id   integer,

      CONSTRAINT loan_spoc_mapping_pk PRIMARY KEY (loan_spoc_map_id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_loan_spoc_loan_number FOREIGN KEY (loan_number)
      REFERENCES public.loan_details (loan_number) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_loan_spoc_spoc_id FOREIGN KEY (spoc_id)
     REFERENCES public.user_info (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
  )
      WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
  );
   ALTER TABLE public.loan_mapping 
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The table records for example are as below,

```
  -----user_info ----
    user_id   |  user_name   | lob_id  |  email_id         |    status_id

     111            abc            5      abc@gmail.com           2
    222             def            5      def@gmail.com           6
     333            ghi            5      ghi@gmail.com           2
     444            jkl            5      jkl@hotmail.com         2
```

-----------user_skill ----------------

```
        user_id  |  skill_id

          111          156
          222          156
          333          156
          444          156
```

-----assignment_details----------------

user_id | role_id | lob_id | assignment_status| assignment_limited_threshold

```
111         11       5          Open
222         11       5          No              
333         11       5        Limited               2
444         11       5        Limited               10


 ------------loan_mapping-----------------

  loan_number |   spoc_id  | loan_spoc_map_id  | lob_id  | appName   

   222333          111          23                    5      SS
   222444          333          24                    5      SS
   222555          333          25                    5      SS
   333452          444          26                    5      SS
   777445          444          27                    5      SS
```

Expected Output is :

```
 user_id
 ---------

   111
   444
```

The Query I tried is not giving the expected result

```
     select ui.user_id from user_info ui
         inner join user_skill lus on lus.skill_id = 156 and lus.user_id = 
              ui.user_id 
        inner join assignment_details ad on                     

        ui.lob_id=ad.lob_id and ui.user_id=ad.user_id and 
        ui.lob_id=5 and ui.status_id=2 where ad.lob_id=5 and 
      ad.role_id=11 and ad.assignment_status='Open' OR 
                        ( ad.assignment_status='Limited' 
   and ad.assignment_limited_threshold > ( select count(loan_number) 
                    from loan_mapping where lob_id=5 and  
             app_name ='SS'))
```

Can you please write query as per my expected output ? Thanks in advance

Comment: The user_id **444** will exclude from your condition `lus.skill_id = 156`. Then how can you expect **444** in your output?

Comment: Sorry. I just corrected.

Comment: Try my answer below, if you are facing any issues, let me know here.

Comment: The user_id 333 has two loans assigned. And, the assignment_limited_threshold column value for that user is '2'. Hence, 333 shouldn't come in the list. But still this query returning user_id 333 along with 111 and 444.

Comment: Ok, I'll check and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, and let me know if you are getting any errors.

You have to keep the brackets specifically for the `OR` condition.

**Schema:**

***user_info Table.***

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_info(
        user_id integer NOT NULL,
         email_id character varying(255),
       user_name character varying(255),
       lob_id  integer NOT NULL,
        status_id integer,
       CONSTRAINT user_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
      ) 
    WITH (
     OIDS=FALSE
    );
INSERT INTO user_info VALUES(111,'abc','abc@gmail.com'  ,5,2);
INSERT INTO user_info VALUES(222,'def','def@gmail.com'  ,5,6);
INSERT INTO user_info VALUES(333,'ghi','ghi@gmail.com'  ,5,2);
INSERT INTO user_info VALUES(444,'jkl','jkl@hotmail.com',5,2);
```

***user_skill table:***

```
    CREATE TABLE public.user_skill
       (
         user_id integer NOT NULL,
         skill_id integer NOT NULL
)
   WITH (
       OIDS=FALSE
    );
INSERT INTO user_skill VALUES(111,156);
INSERT INTO user_skill VALUES(222,156);
INSERT INTO user_skill VALUES(333,156);
INSERT INTO user_skill VALUES(444,156);
```

***assignment_details table:***

```
         CREATE TABLE public.assignment_details
         (
           user_id integer NOT NULL,
          role_id integer NOT NULL,
         lob_id  integer NOT NULL,
         assignment_status character varying,
         assignment_limited_threshold integer,
          CONSTRAINT lsa_assignment_details_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id, 
        role_id, lob_id  )
       )
     WITH (
        OIDS=FALSE
   );

INSERT INTO assignment_details VALUES(111,11,5,'Open',NULL);
INSERT INTO assignment_details VALUES(222,11,5,'No',NULL   );
INSERT INTO assignment_details VALUES(333,11,5,'Limited',2);
INSERT INTO assignment_details VALUES(444,12,5,'Limited',10);
```

***loan_mapping table:***

```
         CREATE TABLE public.loan_mapping 
          (
        loan_number           bigint NOT NULL,
         spoc_id               integer NOT NULL,

       loan_spoc_map_id      integer NOT NULL,
          lob_id   integer,
            app_name VARCHAR(20),

      CONSTRAINT loan_spoc_mapping_pk PRIMARY KEY (loan_spoc_map_id)
  )
      WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
  );
INSERT INTO loan_mapping VALUES(222333,111,23,5,'SS');
INSERT INTO loan_mapping VALUES(222444,333,24,5,'SS');
INSERT INTO loan_mapping VALUES(222555,333,25,5,'SS');
INSERT INTO loan_mapping VALUES(333452,444,26,5,'SS');
INSERT INTO loan_mapping VALUES(777445,444,27,5,'SS');
```

**SQL Query:**

```
select ui.user_id from user_info ui
         inner join user_skill lus on lus.skill_id = 156 and lus.user_id = 
              ui.user_id 
         left join 
         (select spoc_id,count(loan_number) loancount
                    from loan_mapping l where lob_id=5 and  
             app_name ='SS'
             group by spoc_id)uc on uc.spoc_id = ui.user_id
        inner join assignment_details ad on                     
        ui.lob_id=ad.lob_id and ui.user_id=ad.user_id and 
        ui.lob_id=5 and ui.status_id=2 where ad.lob_id=5 and 
      ad.role_id=11 and (ad.assignment_status='Open' OR 
                        (ad.assignment_status='Limited' 
   and ad.assignment_limited_threshold > uc.loancount))
```

And check the output value in the [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6e93ba/8)

It returns the following values only.

```
Output
111
444
```

Comment: **Still the query returning user_id 333 in the eligible list**. Please understand my requirement. Since the **assignment_limited_threshold** value for user_id **333** is **2**  and assignment_status ='Limited' in 'assignment_details' table. And, the number of loans assigned to  user_id 333 is **2**. It should not get considered in eligible list.

Comment: @Karthiksa, I can understand what is your requirement. Check my updated answer.

Comment: One correction done from my side. The role_id for user_id 444 should have been 11. I will check this query in my application and revert back here. thanks Dinesh :)

Comment: I checked in my application. The new query is still including users in the eligible list whose assignment_limited_threshold  value is equal to total number of loans assigned. Could you please write query in some other fashion ? I need this solution today EOD.

Comment: The users may or may not have Loans assigned. So, we should consider both scenarios too! And, **If i change the role_id of 444 to 12 or 11**, that user is coming in result set. So, Your query is not correct. I checked in the SQL Fiddle provided by you.

Comment: Can someother persons try this problem ? Please Assist!

Comment: @Karthiksa, Now I made some changes in my Query, hereafter if you are change the role_id, the users won't come.